# Assign a new variable for every item in list - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the standard pig latin code used in codeacademy. It works well but it's shortcoming is that it only works for one word at a time:

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word or phrase:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    translate = word[1:] + word[0]
    if word[0] != "a" and word[0] != "e" and word[0] != "i" and word[0] != "o" and word[0] != "u":
        new_word = translate + pyg
        print new_word
    else:
        new_word = word + pyg
        print new_word
else:
    print 'Input is empty or illegal'
```

so I wanted to make it so that it could phrases. This is what I came up with:

```
pyg = 'ay'

count = 0

original_input = raw_input('Enter a word or phrase:')

original = original_input

original_list = []

#converts to a list
while " " in original:
    if count > 50:
        break
    word = original[0:original.index(" ")]
    original_list.append(word)
    space = original.index(" ")
    space += 1
    original = original[space:]
    count += 1
#this works great until there is a word left and no spaces i.e. the last word
if len(original) > 0:
    original_list.append(original)
#this adds the last word

print original_list

def pyglatin(phrase):
#old code doesn't work because phrase is a list
        #now I have to translate BACK to a string
        for words in phrase:
            new_word = str(words)
    """this works for one word, how do I assign a new variable for every word if I don't know the phrase length ahead of time"""
```

so that brings me to my question: How do I assign a variable for every item when I don't know how many items I'm going to need, and then be able to call that code back (through the old pyglatin translator)?

Comment: I don't understand, you want a variable for each word but you don't know how many words you have. That's the purpose of a list!

Comment: Hopefully editing to include the code added some clarity

Comment: I don't think it did. Your question seems misguided as you don't actually need to have a separate variable for each item, you just access them in a loop. By the way, to split a sentence into words you can use `words = sentence.split()` instead of that loop you wrote.

Comment: Try splitting the phrase into a list of words using original_list = original.split()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
def latinize(word):
        word = word.lower()
        translate = word[1:] + word[0]
        return (translate if word[0] in 'aeiou' else word) + 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word or phrase:')
print ' '.join(latinize(word) for word in original.split())
```

Example input and output:

```
Enter a word or phrase:Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres
galliaay steay mnisoay divisaay niay partesay tresay
```

But shouldn't you actually move all initial consonants to the end, and not only the first?

Edit:

If you want to move all initial consonants to the end, you can use:

```
def latinize(word):
        word = word.lower()
        firstvowel = min (word.index (v) if v in word else 42042 for v in 'aeiou')
        if firstvowel == 42042: raise Exception ('No vowel in word')
        return word [firstvowel:] + word [:firstvowel] + 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word or phrase:')
print ' '.join(latinize (word) for word in original.split () )
```

Sample input and output:

```
Enter a word or phrase:star chick mess string
arstay ickchay essmay ingstray
```

Comment: You guys tore apart my code and made it so much simpler: I love it!

Answer (score 0):

As Maxime mentioned, lists are useful in this instance, and the string can be converted to a list much easier.  To account for phrases, I would rewrite the code as follows:

```
def trans_word(original):
    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        word = original.lower()
        translate = word[1:] + word[0]
        if word[0] != "a" and word[0] != "e" and word[0] != "i" and word[0] != "o" and word[0] != "u":
            new_word = translate + pyg
            return new_word
        else:
            new_word = word + pyg
            return new_word
    else:
        return "Input is empty or illegal"


def pyglatin(phrase):
    if len(phrase) > 0:
        return " ".join(trans_word(word) for word in phrase)
    else:
        return "Input is empty or illegal"


pyg = 'ay'
count = 0
original_input = raw_input('Enter a word or phrase:')
original_list = original_input.split()

print pyglatin(original_list)
```